# How I can get size of text?

Tags: c#, .net, string, graphics

I want to create a Rectangle for text. But I don't know size of string. 
Now I get size as follow(*it is not valid for string with upper case*):

```
var textSize = e.Graphics.MeasureString(text, e.Appearance.Font);
```

But if my string will be **uppercase** this function will **return wrong value**.

How to get the size of the string if the string in **uppercase**?

Comment: With size you mean `Length`? Because `"soner".Length` and `"SONER".Length` will be the same as `5`. I don't feel I understand your question clearly..

Comment: Use ToLower() string's method

Comment: How do you know it is not valid for uppercase?

Comment: Have you check other overload method of MeasureString().Like MeasureString(String, Font, Int32)

Comment: Ok. I want to draw a rectangle for my string. But I do not know what should be the length from the rectangle.

Comment: `var textSize = e.Graphics.MeasureString(text.ToUpper(), e.Appearance.Font);`?

Comment: See helpful link http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6xe5hazb(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @MatthewWatson, string title = text.ToUpper(); var size = e.Graphics.MeasureString(title, e.Appearance.Font);

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`MeasureString` works for me. Find the following code.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
        {
        public Form1()
            {
            InitializeComponent();
            }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {

            }
        protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
            {
            base.OnPaint(e);
            MeasureStringMin(e);
            }
        private void MeasureStringMin(PaintEventArgs e)
            {

            // Set up string. 
            string measureString = "MEASURE STRING";
            Font stringFont = new Font("Arial", 16);

            // Measure string.
            SizeF stringSize = new SizeF();
            stringSize = e.Graphics.MeasureString(measureString, stringFont);

            // Draw rectangle representing size of string.
            e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(new Pen(Color.Red, 1), 0.0F, 0.0F, stringSize.Width, stringSize.Height);

            // Draw string to screen.
            e.Graphics.DrawString(measureString, stringFont, Brushes.Black, new PointF(0, 0));
            }
        }
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

From [Msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6xe5hazb.aspx)

> To obtain metrics suitable for adjacent strings in layout (for example, when implementing formatted text), use the MeasureCharacterRanges method or one of the MeasureString methods that takes a StringFormat, and pass GenericTypographic. Also, ensure the TextRenderingHint for the Graphics is AntiAlias.